# Getting a channel with new member messages?

Tags: discord.js

Is it possible to get a TextChannel where new member messages are sent? I mean this one, configurable in the server settings:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Guild#systemChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=systemChannel) will give you the channel where system messages ( welcome messages ) are sent